# Not able to get the URL of a opened browser using BrowserFactory.Attach in LeanFT

Tags: leanft

I am trying to get the URL of a Opened Browser using `getOpenURL()` in LeanFT.

My code is below:

```
String url = BrowserFactory.attach(new BrowserDescription.Builder().build()).getOpenURL();
System.out.println("Opened Browser URL is:" +url);
```

It executes with the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.hp.lft.sdk.ReplayObjectNotFoundException: attachApplication
    at com.hp.lft.sdk.internal.ReplayExceptionFactory$1.create(ReplayExceptionFactory.java:34)
    at com.hp.lft.sdk.internal.ReplayExceptionFactory.createOrDefault(ReplayExceptionFactory.java:197)
    at com.hp.lft.sdk.internal.ReplayExceptionFactory.createOrDefault(ReplayExceptionFactory.java:21)
    at com.hp.lft.sdk.internal.web.BrowserErrorHandler.onError(BrowserErrorHandler.java:38)
    at com.hp.lft.sdk.internal.CommunicationClientImpl.handleError(CommunicationClientImpl.java:221)
    at com.hp.lft.sdk.internal.CommunicationClientImpl.send(CommunicationClientImpl.java:96)
    at com.hp.lft.sdk.web.BrowserFactory$BrowserFactoryInstance$3.invoke(BrowserFactory.java:142)
    at com.hp.lft.sdk.web.BrowserFactory$BrowserFactoryInstance$3.invoke(BrowserFactory.java:131)
    at com.hp.lft.sdk.internal.TestObjectOperationWrapper.executeWithEvents(TestObjectOperationWrapper.java:120)
    at com.hp.lft.sdk.internal.TestObjectOperationWrapper.executeWithEvents(TestObjectOperationWrapper.java:97)
    at com.hp.lft.sdk.web.BrowserFactory$BrowserFactoryInstance.attach(BrowserFactory.java:150)
    at com.hp.lft.sdk.web.BrowserFactory.attach(BrowserFactory.java:61)
    at com.optum.comet.utilities.TestWebHierarchy.main(TestWebHierarchy.java:88)
```

What am I doing wrong, could you please advise?

Answer (score 0):

`ReplayObjectNotFoundException` says that the object you tried to use is not found. Basically, the browser description is empty (`new BrowserDescription.Builder()`)

What type of browser is opened? Firefox, Chrome?
If you don't know anything about the opened browsers, you could use `BrowserFactory.GetAllOpenBrowsers`, loop over all the browsers and get the url for each one of them